# Spark with Hive is it possible to push Project phase to HiveTableScan?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using Spark SQL to query data stored in ORC format in Hive.

When I run explain command on the query supplied to `spark.sql(query)` I see the following query plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [col1, col2, col3]
+- *Filter (....)
   +- HiveTableScan [col1, col2, col3, ...col50]
```

Which as I understand queries all the 50 columns from Hive and only then does the filtering in Spark and afterwords selects only actual columns needed.

Is it possible to push down the columns required directly to the Hive, so that they are not loaded all the way to Spark ?

Comment: are you selecting all columns in your  spark.sql(query)  ?

Comment: @GowthamSB no, selecting the ones listed in Project phase i.e. [col1, col2, col3]

Comment: thanks, and may I know what file format you are using?

Comment: I think the problem is with the version. I am using HDP 3 and when I run the same query it is not doing a full scan  `== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 10
+- *(1) Project [account_number#245]
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet crr.transaction[account_number#245,pyear#341,pmonth#342,pdate#343] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: CatalogFileIndex[hdfs://, PartitionCount: 142, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<account_number:string>
a: Unit = ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the below properties are set to default or false?

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.orc.enabled=true");
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=true")
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown=true")
```

These helps you to avoid reading unnecessary columns and take advantage of partition pruning with Hive orc table when your data is distributed among 
different partitions on hdfs.

Set above properties to 'true' and see what your explain plan shows.

You can also get benefitted using partition pruning for orc format with Spark since it need not to scan whole table and can limit the number of partitions that Spark need while querying. It will help in to reduce disk input/ouput operations.

**for example:**

I am running below statement to create a dataframe from Hive orc file format table which is partitioned on column `'country'` & `'tran_date'`.

```
df=spark.sql("""select transaction_date,payment_type,city from test_dev_db.transactionmainhistorytable where country ='United Kingdom' and tran_date='2009-06-01' """)
```

The given table is having several partitions and if we look at the physical plan for the above query, we can see that it has only scanned one partition.

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [transaction_date#69, payment_type#72, city#74]
+- *(1) FileScan orc test_dev_db.transactionmainhistorytable[transaction_date#69,payment_type#72,city#74,country#76,tran_date#77] 
Batched: true, Format: ORC, Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://host/user/vikct001/dev/hadoop/database/test_dev..., 
*PartitionCount: 1,* PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(country#76), isnotnull(tran_date#77), (country#76 = United Kingdom), (tran_date#77 = 2..., 
PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<transaction_date:timestamp,payment_type:string,city:string>
```

see `"PartitionCount: 1"` and also PartitionFilters is set to not null.

Similarly, you can pushed down filters if you have specified any filters in the query.
Here, like I am using city column to filtered out the data.

```
df=spark.sql("""select transaction_date,payment_type,city from test_dev_db.transactionmainhistorytable where country ='United Kingdom' and tran_date='2009-06-01' and city='London' """)


== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [transaction_date#104, payment_type#107, city#109]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(city#109) && (city#109 = London))
   +- *(1) FileScan orc test_dev_db.transactionmainhistorytable[transaction_date#104,payment_type#107,city#109,country#111,tran_date#112] 
   Batched: true, Format: ORC, Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://host/user/vikct001/dev/hadoop/database/test_dev..., 
   PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(country#111), isnotnull(tran_date#112), (country#111 = United Kingdom), (tran_date#112..., 
   PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(city), EqualTo(city,London)], ReadSchema: struct<transaction_date:timestamp,payment_type:string,city:string>
```

Above you can see that `PushedFilters` is not null and it has a country column with a certain value which needs to be filtered.

Comment: Yes, now I'm seeing 
== Physical Plan ==
*Project 
+- *Filter 
+- *FileScan orc ... Batched: false, Format: ORC, Location: ..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: ...
So seems now the file scan instead of table scan is used, is it faster ? also strange to see PushedFilters: [], I assumed the filter phase would migrate here.
Are these conf options documented somewhere? I can not find them in https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/configuration.html, which I'm using, also maybe you know if they supported by Cloudera distribution ?